# $this->params['prefix'] is detected only if $_SESSION values exists

Tags: session, cakephp, parameters

At the moment I'm using Cakephp...

This webpage contains an admin section and a "normal" section... you can access to the admin section using "...site/admin".

If the user writes in the url "...site/admin" then it's suppossed to be redirected to an admin logon section...

However, if he tries to go to the "site" directly, then he will also be redirected to another logon section but for access to the normal site.

The problem is... my code is not working... if I try to access to the admin site, then I'm redirected to the normal logon section and I must write my credentials... then after that, I'm able to go to the admin site (and prompted for admin credentials, which is ok)

If all of this sounds confusing, you have to know that:

Administrator section -> needs admin credentials

Normal section -> needs normal credentials

but this is what's happening right now:

Administrator section -> needs admin credentials -> needs normal credentials

This is the code, it's located on AppController (the program heads directly to redirect(site.com) and I don't understand why)

```
function beforeFilter() 
    {
        session_start();
        if($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin'){ //Si se quiere ir a la sección de admin...
            if($this->Session->check('Admin.logged')){ //si esta logueado...
                $this->layout = 'admin'; //Pone el layout de admin
            }else{ //Si no esta logeado un admin...
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'info','action'=>'login','admin'=>false)); //lo redirige al login.
            }
        }
        else //si no está en admin, está en todas las demás páginas, a las cuales no debería poder entrar si no está logueado...
        {
            //si le ponés test=true te deja entrar igual y te llena los valores de sesión, esto es más que nada para poder hacer las pruebas de forma local...
            $value = $this->request->query('test');
            if (isset($value))
            {
                $_SESSION['web']['nombre'] = 'John';
                $_SESSION['web']['apellido'] = 'Doe';
            }
            if(!isset($_SESSION['web']['nombre']))
                $this->redirect('http://www.thesite.com.ar');
        }
    }
```

It basically doesn't detect I'm using the prefix "admin" UNTIL I have logged with normal (test) credentials (they are written automatically if you do "site?test")

I hope this is clear...

Comment: Don't ever call session_start() in a CakePHP app.  The framework is supposed to take care of this for you.  Similarly, don't directly access $_SESSION.  Use the session component, for the same reason you should not use session_start().  Also, why do you have two separate login processes depending on whether you're an admin or a user?  Please make use of the Auth component, and make use of a field in your user table to indicate whether the user that's logged in is either an admin or a regular user.

Comment: Indeed: Leverage the framework - don't fight it.

Comment: There's two separate login processes because one section is for administrators (to control website internal content) and another is for viewing that content, they are completely different...

Also, I have no control over 95% of the webpage because it's from my client and I can't modify their code, so I have to adapt.

Comment: Those answers are useful but don't solve my problem, the question is, why prefix admin is not detected? why it's detected when session variables are up?

Comment: I solved this by directly logging normal credentials when the users tries to go to the admin page...